# Question about Gauss divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The Divergence Theorem says that for $\Omega \subset  \mathbb{R}^n$
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot F = \int_{\partial\Omega} F \cdot n $$
where $n$ is the outward normal.

Assuming that $F$ is a smooth vector field, does the Divergence Theorem require $\partial \Omega$ to have $n$ dimensional Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: I wrote a comment earlier, but the answer was deleted, but I'll go with yes: I believe Stokes requires that $\Omega$ be a compact $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary, and thus $\partial\Omega$ is a bounded $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold, so has $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure 0.

Comment: That was my answer, I mistakenly did read the $n$ as general, using a measure to define area, but it seems this question might run down to if the border has zero volume or not. I am still a bit puzzled why this is asked in context of the divergence theorem.